Is your question about cryptography *and not crypto-currency*?
When asking a question on the main site, the following text appears on the right hand side of the screen:

Is your question about cryptography?
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Share your research.
If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

Considering that:

The term "crypto" has been usurped in the popular lexicon and now means "crypto-currency" to many people
Many people see "crypto.stackexchange" and post questions that are very crypto-currency specific and a better fit for a site like bitcoin.stackexchange

Is it possible to include additional text in the question guidelines? Something like:

Note that specific questions about crypto-currency such as bitcoin/ethereum/etc are not on-topic here.
There is a crypto-currency tag for discussing the cryptography that crypto-currency uses. Questions about wallets, crypto-currency software, prices, etc. are not appropriate for this site.

There is a similar question on meta here that appears to have been declined due to the nature of the specific information that the user wanted to incorporate into the guidelines. Since the requested changes here are for different information, this question appears to not be a duplicate.
We could also have this information in the section on What topics can I ask about here?, specifically in the subsection "I'm confused as to where my question belongs; there are so many sites!".

We can request an actual warning pop-up. But I suppose the requirements to getting that are rather strict.

I have now requested clarification (in a place for mods-only) on how bad of a problem this has to become before we should request advanced counter-measures.


We could also have this information in the section on What topics can
  I ask about here?, specifically in the subsection "I'm confused as to
  where my question belongs; there are so many sites!".

I have implemented this preliminarily, it now redirects people to the specialized sites for BTC, ETH, Iota and Monero and for more general non-mechanism related questions to BTC.
If you are unhappy with the current formulation (like I kinda am) I suggest you answer the Meta question on help-center updates I just made.

As for the more advanced request on changing the box, this is nothing mods can change and I have requested guidance on this which I'll forward here as soon as I have it.
The guidance we got is "whenever you feel it is bad enough", so I'm arbitrarily defining the threshold of at least one such cryptocurrency question per day averaged over a two-week period at which point please ping one of the mods in chat or make a post here on meta and the mods will have a CM look at it and potentially implement more "counter-measures".
